# How can I preload assets I know I will be requesting via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, winamp

I have a [page](https://jordaneldredge.com/projects/winamp2-js/) which needs to load and process two large-ish files via ajax. I know in advance that I am going to need to download them, but I can't start the ajax request until another large javascript file has loaded and is ready to process them.

The result is that I end up fetching the large javascript and the large assets in serial rather than parallel, which I think could be nearly twice as fast.

Is it possible to get the browser to preload these assets?

You can see in the below screenshot that `production.min.js` has to be loaded before `base-2.91.wsz` and `llama-2.91.mp3` even start downloading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) would do the trick. Straight from the documentation:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {    
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.    
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]    
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"    
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {    
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );    
  }    
});
```

So you would execute all three calls in parallel and continue when all three are finished.

Comment: I was hoping to load these resources in parallel with my initial javascript payload. I already have for loading them once my javascript app has downloaded and initialized.

Comment: Is production.min.js loaded like `<script src="..." />` ? If so, you could load jQuery first, then use `$.script()` to load production.min.js and the other two resources in parallel.